# Webpack static field

Tags: javascript, webpack

why doesn't webpack support static field?

When i try

```
export class Game {
#lasttime = 0;
#FRAME_DURATION = 1000 / 144;
```

I get an error

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (2:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders.
What is the problem?

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'js/main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#modules:

> Note that webpack will not alter any code other than import and export statements. If you are using other ES2015 features, make sure to use a transpiler such as Babel or Bublé via webpack's loader system.

You need to configure babel-loader yourself, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#root

Comment: I have bare code.  the only plugin besides webpack that costs is htmlplugin.  I don't understand why without babel in any way

Comment: As far as I know, webpack uses acorn to parse the source code under the hood, and the static class field needs https://github.com/acornjs/acorn-stage3 to parse which is not enabled in webpack https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/f07921a6572dbf713905c610bd0c8dbc9b35e87b/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js#L8.